# There is a problem I am facing while getting data from firebase I am getting empty array

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, data-retrieval

I am facing an error while I am retrieving data from firebase. **I am using React JS and Firebase Firestore for data storeing.**

The problem is when I use the **useEffect()** hook to get data at the start of the application.
and saving the data into **array** but When I refresh the page, I got the empty array. When I do some task in the code like **change the text on the front end or perform changes in the code like `console.log("Birds Details", birdsData)` to `console.log("birds details anytext", birdsData)`** like edit them the array get data from the firebase firestore.

I will share the code that I write to do the task and the screen shoot of the problem.

**all the import**

```
import { getDoc, orderBy, query, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import { birdsDataCollectionRef } from "../../firestore.collections";
```

**code for getting data from the firebase**

```
const [birdsData, setBirdsData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(birdsDataCollectionRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapShot) => {
      setBirdsData(
        querySnapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
    console.log("bird details array", birdsData);
  }, []);
```

**Empty Array of data I receive**
[Image of Empty Array Image from the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNFjv.png)

**response I got on console log**

```
[]   ViewBirdsDetails.js:19
[]   ViewBirdsDetails.js:19
```

**response I got after changing some code from behind with refreshing the page**

[Response Image After Changing code without refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFHpK.png)

I am using **useState Hook** and **firebase firestore**

please Help me with my issue.

Comment: state updates are maybe asynchronous... so you could see after the re-render ... you can put the log outside

Comment: It's not about the logs... The problem is that when the web application is refreshed I got an empty array.... Which supposed to be consist of data got from firebase firestore....

Answer (score 1):

As user KcH commented, this is the expected behavior as both reading from Firestore and setting state are asynchronous operations. By the time your `console.log("bird details array", birdsData)` code runs, neither of those has completed yet.

You can most easily see this by adding some more logging:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const q = query(birdsDataCollectionRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
  console.log('starting query');
  onSnapshot(q, (querySnapShot) => {
    console.log('got data');
  });
  console.log("started query");
}, []);
```

The output of this is:

> starting query
>
> started query
>
> got data

This is probably not the order that you expected, but it is working as exactly as designed - and explains why your logging shows an empty array.

---

To address this is always the same: any code that needs the data from the data, needs to be inside the `onSnapshot` callback handler, be called from there, or otherwise synchronized. Your `setBirdsData` is an example of such a synchronization mechanism, but your `console.log` does not synchronize.

The simple fix is to log the data inside the `onSnapshot` callback handler:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const q = query(birdsDataCollectionRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
  onSnapshot(q, (querySnapShot) => {
    const data = querySnapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      data: doc.data(),
    }))
    setBirdsData(data);
    console.log("bird details array", data);
  });
}, []);
```

So here we moved the logging into the callback to handle the asynchronous nature of `onSnapshot` and assign the data to a local variable to handle the asynchronous nature of `setBirdsData`.

Comment: This is explained well, Thanks Frank 

Comment: What about the data that is in the array of birdsData   const [birdsData, setBirdsData] = useState([]);... I have used the useStateHook to save the data which I got from the firestore. I got empty array at the load of the page. But when the app Re render it got data. How to solve this problem... please guide me...

Comment: **Here is the complete code**


`const ViewBirdsDetails = () => {
  const [birdsData, setBirdsData] = useState([]);
  let serialNumber = 1;
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(birdsDataCollectionRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapShot) => {
      const data = querySnapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        data: doc.data(),
      }));
      setBirdsData(data);
      console.log("Here is the data", birdsData);
    });
  }, []);`

Comment: You can't log `birdsData` at the end there, since `setBirdsData` is asynchronous too. That's why the code in my answer logs `data` (a local variable) instead of `birdsData` (a state variable).